# configure IPv6 ACL on interface WS-C3750X-48

Tags: cisco, switch, ipv6, acl

I am using  WS-C3750X-48 model switch. license is lanbase. I have activated cmd on my switch:

`sdm prefer dual-ipv4-and-ipv6 routing`. Then i did reload. After that, i will able to config IPv6 on switch:

`ipv6 access-list lab` but i am not able to configure on

```
interface Gi1/0/1:ipv6 ?
IPv6 interface subcommands:
mld MLD interface commands
nd IPv6 interface Neighbor Discovery subcommands.
```

i need to create ACL on my interface to control IPv6 subnet. Anyone can advise me which license i need to buy IPbase or IP services. So far i found some guys advising for IPbase which support ACL list.

Please help me double confirm.

Thank you

Comment: That license is a layer-2 license, but you want to configure layer-3, so you need the IPBase or above license. (IP is a layer-3 protocol.)

Comment: so if i do upgrade IPBase license still i will get LANbase license functionality ? i mean, my existing L2 network services will not affected ???

Comment: That is correct. You are really just adding basic layer-3 functionality to the switch, not taking anything away.

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in the comments, the LANBase license is a layer-2 license, but you are trying to use layer-3 commands. At the very least, you need the IPBase license.

Probably, you want to create an SVI for the VLAN to define the network (subnet) on the switch, and that is where you would place the ACL. If you want to configure a physical interface as a layer-3 interface, you would need to use the interface `no switchport` command to be able to assign IP addressing and layer-3 ACLs.